# How do I fix a margin that is affecting a whole row of buttons

Tags: css

I have a few rows of buttons.
I'm trying to make it so that if I press a button it'll get a margin of 5px so it'll look like it clicked.
doing so the whole row of buttons is getting the margin as well which is terribly annoying.
How do I get around that?

```css
button {
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
    margin-bottom: 7.5px;
    margin-left: 7.5px;
    margin-right: 7.5px;
    background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
}
button:active {
    margin-top: 12.5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addText(7)" id="num7">7</button>
<button onclick="addText(8)" id="num8">8</button>
<button onclick="addText(9)" id="num9">9</button>
```

Comment: Not understand. You put a margin on purpose but you don't want a margin? Well remove that margin?

Comment: Or you want the button to become smaller like pressing a keyboard? Just reduce the width/height or zoom using css

Comment: Hi there! Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Additional help asking questions can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Why not change the background colour of the button to represent a click?

Comment: I wanna put a margin on one button, the one that is being pressed. When I do (using button:active) all the other buttons in the row are getting the margin as well. that is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the buttons a vertical-align property of top instead of the default of baseline:

```css
button {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  margin-left: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  vertical-align: top;
}

button:active {
  margin-top: 12.5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<button id="num7">7</button>
<button id="num8">8</button>
<button id="num9">9</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are actually using the selector correctly, I made an example and couldn't find the problem.

In any case, if you want to add (and keep) that margin, you should use `:active` and `:focus`, like so:

```
.btn:active, .btn:focus{
       margin:5px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywaqjp6x/1/

If not, you can use `:active` only, like so:

```
.btn:active{
  margin:5px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywaqjp6x/

Comment: That just makes it stay longer instead of come back to original state :(

Comment: I've edited the post and added the code I made to explain better what I mean, If you press a button you'll see the problem.